# read the last 5 minutes from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I get some data every 5-15 seconds from football/soccer and I save them in csv files.
I have two columns with the time, the one is 'tm'(time minutes 0-90) and the other is 'ts'(time seconds 0-60) to get some idea I provide some photo from excel:

[image: CSV Table]

Now I'm trying to get the exactly last five minutes result from the csv but I have no idea how.
I can also change the code that imports the data to csv if there is any way to make it easier to read and calculate the last 5 minutes.

The code I use to read all the `csv` files and try to get the last 30 lines and see if is 5 minutes but is 4-6 minutes so I don't get occurred data.

```py
csv_list = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
for fn in csv_list:
    filepath = os.path.join(mypath + fn)
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        row_count = sum(1 for row in f)
        f.close()
        if row_count >= 30:
            with open(filepath, "r") as f:
                for line in (f.readlines()[-30:]):
                    line = (line.strip().split(","))
                    minutes.append(line[0])
                print(minutes, line[27])
                minutes.clear()
        else:
            print("is less")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know my solution is not the best but anw you can save the timestamp to each record
=> get last X (the number of record you know for sure that larger than number of record can have in 5 minutes) rows.
=> get all row in X row which timestap of row larger than (now substract 5 minutes delta)

```
csv_list = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
for fn in csv_list:
filepath = os.path.join(mypath + fn)
timestamp_to_check = time.time() - 5 * 60  # update here
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    row_count = sum(1 for row in f)
    f.close()
    if row_count >= X:
        with open(filepath, "r") as f:
            for line in (f.readlines()[-X:]):
                line = (line.strip().split(","))
                row_timestamp = line[0]  # update here
                if row_timestamp > timestamp_to_check:  # update here
                    minutes.append(line[0])
            print(minutes, line[27])
            minutes.clear()
    else:
        print("is less")
```